# Sending 2D Int Array with MPI_Send and Recv

Tags: c, int, mpi, multidimensional-array, multiple-processes

I am trying to send a 2D integer array of arbitrary length from slave processes to the master but I keep getting a segmentation fault. As MPI is quite difficult to debug, I'm not certain that the issue has to do with the send/recv but if it's not that then it will have to be with the way I am allocating the arrays themselves.

I followed a previous question on here in regards to ensuring that the memory allocated to the array is contiguous but that still didn't fix the segmentation fault.

Below are some sections of my code:

Create array:

```
int** create2DArray(int sizeX, int sizeY)
{
    int* data = (int *) malloc(sizeX * sizeY * sizeof(int));
    int** array= (int **) malloc(sizeX * sizeof(int*));

    int i;

    for (i=0; i<sizeX; i++)
    {
        array[i] = &(data[sizeY * i]);
    }

    return array;
}
```

Initialise arrays:

```
if(rank==0)
{
    display = x11setup(&win, &gc, width, height);
    pixels = create2DArray(X_RESN, Y_RESN);
}
else
{
    xStart = xPixels * (rank - 1);
    xFinish = xStart + xPixels;
    pixels = create2DArray(xPixels, Y_RESN);
}
```

Send:

```
MPI_Send(&pixels[0][0], xPixels * Y_RESN, MPI_INT, 0, type, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Recv:

```
for(i = 1; i < processes; i++)
{
    int** pixelChunk = create2DArray(xPixels, Y_RESN);
    MPI_Recv(&pixelChunk[0][0], xPixels * Y_RESN, MPI_INT, i, type, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    int xStart = xPixels * (i - 1);
    int xFinish = xStart + xPixels;

    int k;

    for(j = xStart; j < xFinish; j++)
    {
        for(k = 0; k < Y_RESN; k++)
        {
            pixels[j][k] = pixelChunk[j - (xPixels * i - 1)][k];
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly which operation results in a segfault?

Comment: Your code seems a bit complex, i.e. We don't see here where `xPixels` come from for example. Have you tried simplifying the code to only sending a fixed array, receiving it and trying to make sure that it is transmitted correctly? The sending/receiving code looks legit.

Comment: Are you sure that `X_RESN` is dividable by `processes - 1`?

Comment: int xPixels = X_RESN / (processes - 1);

It's the 'column width' of the pixels, used to split them up for each slave processor. The resolution is 600x600 and I'm splitting them up in 15 block of 40x600.

Comment: Yes 16 processes, xPixels = 600 / (16-1)

Comment: The issue is that MPI is hard to debug as it doesn't give a line of execution that causes the issue (ie seg fault)

Comment: You can at least try inserting debugging prints and find the problematic line. Start with `np = 2` :D

Comment: Haha I guess... :/ I hate MPI, can't wait until this course is over lol. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line looks suspicious:

```
pixels[j][k] = pixelChunk[j - (xPixels * i - 1)][k];
```

For example, say we have `np = 2`, so we're left with a single chunk, then

```
i = 1;
xStart = 0;
j = 0;
xPixels = 600;
pixelChunk[0 - (600 * 1 - 1)[k] == pixelChunk[-599][k]
```

Doesn't look right, does it?

This?

```
pixels[j][k] = pixelChunk[j - xPixels * (i - 1)][k];
```

The send/recv code is allright probably.

Comment: I implemented that change and it still seg faults unfortunately :/

Comment: Okay, got a few weird results...I ran it with `-np 2` and it worked perfectly. When I tried `-np 3 or -np 4` I got the seg fault.

Comment: Fixed it. Apart from the issues you already found, I had another problem with the actions I was execution on the data before I sent it. I had the for loop starting at xPixels rather than 0 so it seg faulted. (I was forgetting that even though it is calculating a specific section of pixels, the idexz on that process will go form 0 to xPixel, rather than xStart to xFinish). Thank you for your help, it is greatly appreciated :)